# Google Datastore: how to retrieve entities with children?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I only found the way to get children entities by parent one.

But is there any way to retrieve the list of parent entities (by some parent entity's properties filter) with their children in single call?

**(Pseudo query):**

```
SELECT * FROM parents (with children) WHERE parent.property1=...
```

**Result should be like this:**

```
- (parent1, child1, child2)
- (parent2, child3, child4)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if you store the parents and children as separate entities. However, if the children for a parent is expected to be small, then you can consider storing them as embedded struct slice. Then as you query the parent entities and retrieve them you will have access to their children.

Comment: It’s not currently possible to refactor the structure, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

> **The short answer is no.**

## Some background

> Entities in a Datastore mode database form an [ancestor path](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths), which means a hierarchically structured space, similar to the directory structure of a file system.

## Workarounds:

> Depending on your needs there are a couple things that you could do:

1. You could retrieve each parent and their children individually in multiple calls and then combine all the parts together.
2. You could use Special query types, such as [kindless queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queries#kindless_queries), which is a query with no kind and no ancestor filter that retrieves all of the entities of an application from Datastore, so you can gather the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this qualifies as an answer but I have the same scenario and below are the two options I am considering.

The scenario I am in is an Employer kind and an Employee kind. The Employee is a child of Employer but the same Employee can be part of multiple Employers.

I need to find all Employers a specific Employee is part of.

#### Option 1 (the one I think I will go with)

Have a third entity for a reverse lookup. The key will be the Employee's last part of the key with an additional property to hold the list of Employers' keys.

Every time an Employer/Employee relationship changes I will also update the reverse lookup kind.

#### Option 2

Have the last part of the Employee's key saved separately in the same entity as an indexed property so that I can search by it (and then able to find each of those entities' parent key).